# What is TeeChart Library alternative in Linux?

Tags: linux, teechart

I have found TeeChart library was wonderful to create 2D chart based on mathematic/physic simulation formula in C/C++/Java/Delphi. My friends used TeeChart in Microsoft Visual Studio and Delphi IDE and they are successful creating Haar Wavelet simulation and plot its simulation in **animated** 2D chart. They all use Windows. I use Linux.

What is TeeChart alternative in Linux? For plotting program into animated chart and precisely.

Answer (score 4):

There are 5 TeeChart versions you can use to work with linux: PHP, Java, JavaScript, .Net and VCL/FMX:

1. We've managed to run TeeChart for **PHP**, you can find an example [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10501)
2. The **Java** version is another cross-platform version that should work under Linux, I recommend taking a look at this [link](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10235&p=42636&hilit=linux#p42636)
3. You can use **JavaScript** that should work under Linux without problems.
4. TeeChart **.NET** can also run on linux under Mono. You need the SourceCode version for it and build the sources with the `MONO` [preprocessor symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
5. TeeChart **VCL/FMX** also works on linux with CrossVCL/FMXLinux. You need the SourceCode version for that.

I hope it helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's equivalent to TeeChart in the sense that it has every feature TeeChart has but many Linux users like GNUplot which runs on Windows as well as Linux. It has it's own scripting language but I believe there is now an API for it? Google for something like "C++ and gnuplot". It's free. I have used it only for very simple line graphs so I can't speak to it's capabilities but take a look at some of the example graphs at the GNUplot site.

Python has a library for accessing GNUplot.  Since Python runs on Linux as well as Win the pair make a cross-platform solution.

There is also MatPlotLib (sp?) for Linux.